# Extending JPanel and setting BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing

When I create a panel and setLayout to BoxLayout this works:

```
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    pan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

However, when the class is named `Pan` and `extends JPanel` I try to do this in the constructor of the class:

```
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(Pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

I get the error

> Pan cannot be resolved to a variable

What is the problem here?

Comment: `pan`  is not `Pan`. Java is case-sensitive. So write it always in the same way.

Comment: @davidxxx I did not do anything wrong with the case-sensitivity because its two different cases. Classes should have capital letter, while variables do not.

Comment: **Pan cannot be resolved to a variable**  when you write : `setLayout(new BoxLayout(Pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));` because you declared it `pan` above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pan` would replace your use of `JPanel`:

```
Pan pan = new Pan();
pan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Or:

```
JPanel pan = new Pan();
pan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Edit: You can also set the layout in your Pan class, something like:

```
public class Pan extends JPanel {
    public Pan() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, however, how would you create an object within its constructor? Sounds funny

Comment: Yes, thanks! Worked with the edit alternative. Learned something new :)